# passing data using Arraylist<Object>

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

I am having a problem displaying data from my DB in a list view. the below is the code from for my display method.

**Display**

```
public ArrayList<Object> display(String rows) {

    ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_PACKNAME,
            KEY_PACKRENT, KEY_SIMRATE, KEY_NATMINSBUN, KEY_INTMINSBUN,
            KEY_INTMINSRATE, KEY_NATSMSBUN,
                            KEY_NATSMSRATE, KEY_INTSMSBUN, KEY_INTSMSRATE, 
                            KEY_MMSBUN, KEY_MMSRATE, KEY_DATALBUN,
            KEY_DATALRATE };
    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();


    if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        do
        {   
            rowArray.add(cursor.getLong(0));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(2));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(3));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(4));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(5));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(6));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(7));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(8));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(9));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(10));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(11));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(12));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(13));
            rowArray.add(cursor.getString(14));

    }         while (cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
    }

    return rowArray;


}
```

**This is the Arraylist**

```
            EtiTariffDatabase test = new EtiTariffDatabase(this);

    TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_etipackname);
    TextView TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s_etipackrent);
    TextView TV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srentalrate);
    TextView TV3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.snationalbun);
    TextView TV4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seintbun);
    TextView TV5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.senatsmsbun);
    TextView TV6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seintsmsbun);
    TextView TV7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sedatalocalbun);


    test.open();

    try
    {
    ArrayList<Object> row = test.display(null);



    TV.setText((String)row.get(1));
    TV1.setText((String)row.get(2));
    TV2.setText((String)row.get(3));
    TV3.setText((String)row.get(4));
    TV4.setText((String)row.get(6));
    TV5.setText((String)row.get(8));
    TV6.setText((String)row.get(10));
    TV7.setText((String)row.get(12));


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Retrieve Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    test.close();


}
```

the exception I catch is:

**04-07 16:48:23.759: E/Retrieve Error(4134): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0**
04-07 16:48:23.829: W/System.err(4134): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
04-07 16:48:23.829: W/System.err(4134):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)

I have been trying to play around for a long time. It worked initially but I deleted the DB and recreated it. From then no data gets displayed with me having the above error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any data-rows inside your database? From what the Exception says you try to access a field in the array but the array itself is empty.

Everything looks like it should work, but when there are no data in the database the function `display` will return an ArrayList that is empty (`row.size` should be 0 then).

So test for emptyness:

```
try
{
    ArrayList<Object> row = test.display(null);

    if(row.size != 0) {
        TV.setText((String)row.get(1));
        TV1.setText((String)row.get(2));
        TV2.setText((String)row.get(3));
        TV3.setText((String)row.get(4));
        TV4.setText((String)row.get(6));
        TV5.setText((String)row.get(8));
        TV6.setText((String)row.get(10));
        TV7.setText((String)row.get(12));
    }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Retrieve Error", e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
test.close();
```

Comment: It shows my array does not have objects. There is data in my DB coz I pulled my DB file to check this. I think it has something to do with creating the object array which I have done.

Comment: The array-creation and filling shouldn't be a problem, you have done that correctly.
I think something is wrong with the query so that the cursor returns an empty set of data. You could check that by using `Log.d("cursor",cursor.getCount()+"");`

Comment: found out the issue. the DB was not getting created. fixed that and boom, it all works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> 04-07 16:48:23.759: E/Retrieve Error(4134): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

That clearly indicates that your method returns an empty `ArrayList`. Indexes start from 0 and not 1 (which is not related to your error, but you should correct that too). If there is no data in your table the ArrayList will not contain any elements.

You are better off returning a [value object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) instead of individually adding each column to an `ArrayList` (again, not related to your error but this is a good practice).